# what is the functionality of these methods "isIgnoreText()" and " isIgnoreGraphic()" in JAVAFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-11

I recently started working with javafx.
I changed the jdk from 8 to 11 and using JAVAFX 15 version  in the project and there is a class that uses these method "isIgnoreText()" and "isIgnoreGraphic()" here am getting error like these

The method isIgnoreGraphic() from the type LabeledSkinBase<TableRow> is
not visible
- The method isIgnoreText() from the type LabeledSkinBase<TableRow> is not
visible

private void updateShowColumns() {

```
    boolean newValue = (isIgnoreText() && isIgnoreGraphic());

    if (showColumns == newValue)
        return;

    showColumns = newValue;

    this.getSkinnable().requestLayout();

}
```

I am not able to understand what this method does and how to rewrite this code for JavaFX 15

Comment: If those methods still exist, and the error "not visible" suggests they do, then note you can easily use your IDE to navigate to their source code and see the implementation. This will help you understand what they do. Also check out the [`Labeled#contentDisplay`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#contentDisplayProperty) property.

Comment: they probably do the same before and after, nothing changed (except now might have to use reflection or find another way, as @Slaw already suggested). Looks like you never understood what your code is/was doing, that's generally a direct way to desaster, particularly when eating forbidden fruits (like using internal api). Read the sources and find out what they are doing ..